# Code restricting: Create of more than one object in private constructor in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to create a code in C# for Private constructor.

I want that it should allow only one object to be created but when I try to create more than one a message showing `no more object can be created` should be shown.

I  don't want to use static constructor in this code.

How do I do that in `C#`?

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use a static constructor? When you have strange requirements, you should explain them. This does sound like you basically want the singleton pattern, much as I dislike it - http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may use static counter or flag that will be set in your private counstructor to show that at least one instance were created.

But first of all, I suggest you to pay attention to Singleton pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, this is the classic singleton pattern:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass Instance;
    private MyClass()
    {
        if (Instance != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("no more object can be created");
        // do other constructor logic
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

Please note that synchronization has been left out. This code need synchronization for thread safe purpose.

Comment: No, that's *not* the classic singleton pattern. The singleton pattern prevents you from even *trying* to create more than one instance. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx for normal singleton implementations in C#.

Comment: Why can't it be the classic singleton pattern? Singleton pattern is about enforcing that there is only one instance ever of the class, it not dictate how to achieve that. A property to get the only instance is irrelevant here.

Comment: Well you've got a private constructor, so arguably you *are* preventing more than one instance from ever being created - but that's actually preventing *any* instances from being created. You need some code to call that constructor. What you've presented is not a proper implementation of the singleton pattern, basically... and every sensible implementation of the singleton pattern I've ever seen enforces it by not *exposing* any way of trying to create more than one instance. Why present code which clearly isn't useful in its current form?

Comment: If you take a small code snippet that just for illustrating some simple thing and require it fully future proof, fully usable, then so be it.

Comment: I'm saying that claiming something is "the classic singleton pattern" and then providing useless code which is a long way from any regular implementation of the singleton pattern is unhelpful.